go_router/navigator go back to home before closing app?
I am following this tutorial which implements the following structure:
https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-bottom-navigation-bar-nested-routes-gorouter/
GoRouter
└─ StatefulShellRoute
    ├─ StatefulShellBranch
    │   └─ GoRoute('/a')
    │      └─ GoRoute('details')
    └─ StatefulShellBranch
        └─ GoRoute('/b')
            └─ GoRoute('details')

My question is, when you are at /b (or /c, or any other stafefulshellbranch root), how can you make it to always go to /a ("home") first before exiting app?
